# script 'D:/xampp/htdocs/wp-login.php' not found or unable to stat

Tags: php, .htaccess, xampp, httpd.conf, error-log

I am getting this error in my xampp error.log file, but the wp-login.php file does not exist in mentioned path. Here is the error..

```html
[:error] [pid 804:tid 896] [client 183.83.36.131:37897] script 'D:/xampp/htdocs/wp-login.php' not found or unable to stat
```

Some people are telling me to check in the following files for wp-login.php redirection

```html
1) httpd.conf 

2) httpd-vhosts.conf and 

3).htaccess
```

but wp-login.php redirection is not there in all the above files.

Please help me to solve the error. thankyou

Comment: How about value in database?

Comment: @Justinas, What value in db?